# Why are derived functors triangulated?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-functors, kan-extension

I am following Verdier's notion of derived functors as Kan extensions along the localization $K(\mathcal{A}) \to D(\mathcal{A})$ of the homotopy category of complexes to the derived category.

In the treatment I am reading, the fact that $RF$ is triangulated follows from the explicit construction and noting that the additive functor $F$ must preserve cones.

I am wondering if there is a more intrinsic reason that $RF$ must be triangulated. It does not seem like the Kan extension should have any way of ``knowing'' about the triangulated structure and therefore it seems surprising from the definition that such an object ought to respect the triangulated structure.

Because $F$ preserves cones, it is clear that $K(F) : K(\mathcal{A}) \to K(\mathcal{A})$ is triangulated. So is there a general reason that the Kan extension of such a triangulated functor is again triangulated?

Is there more interplay between the Kan extension and the exact triangles that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure Verdier uses Kan extensions? Those categories don't have colimits.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Derived functors in the sense of Verdier are Kan extensions by definition, but not necessarily pointwise or absolute. As it turns out they are often absolute Kan extensions and therefore have a colimit universal property.

Comment: @zhenlin it must be indexed by a category with final object then. The derived category is a localization of the homotopy category and the universal property of a localization yields the exactness of derived functors. That's the easiest way to see it IMHO.